# Qt - Creating Icon Button

Tags: c++, qt, qaction

I'm trying to create buttons similar to zoom-in, zoom-out on Google Maps; I want buttons that are only as big as the icon:

http://codegeekz.com/wp-content/uploads/google-maps-jquery.jpg

(I'm sorry for not posting the image, not enough reputation apparently).

I am trying to use QAction but for some reason, the buttons are not appearing. I have used QAction to create buttons in another project but copying all of the relevant code has not proven successful (the instances simply do not appear). These are the essentials:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QAction>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected slots:
    void addEntry();

private:
    QAction *addButton;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *container = new QVBoxLayout();

    //Horizontal add/subtract layout------------------------------------

    QHBoxLayout *layer1 = new QHBoxLayout();

    QAction *addButton = new QAction((QIcon("/home/kyle/Desktop/add1.png")),"Add Entry", this);

    addAction(addButton);

    connect(addButton, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(addEntry()));

    //Scroll Layout------------------------------------

    QHBoxLayout *layer2 = new QHBoxLayout();
    ...

    container->addLayout(layer1);
    container->addLayout(layer2);

    window->setLayout(container);
    setCentralWidget(window);
}

void
MainWindow::addEntry(){
    ...
}
```

I have:

- Tried addAction() on a blank widget, and adding that to the layout.
- Declared the QAction object in .h file (common problem with using QPainter)
- Tried using QPushButton (Extremely ugly but works.)

Any ideas on what's wrong, or recommendations for other button-like objects are appreciated. Also feel free to ask questions. Ultimately, the buttons I wish to create are little widgets that I can manipulate with QHBoxLayout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. When you call `addAction(addButton);`, Where do you intend to add the action. Example: `ui->mainToolBar->addAction(addButton);`
2. `QPushButton` will meet your requirement. You can style the push button using style sheet.

**Example:**

```
    QPushButton *addButton = new QPushButton(QIcon(":/plus.png"),"");
    QString buttonStyle = "QPushButton{border:none;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255,100);}";
    addButton->setStyleSheet(buttonStyle); // Style sheet
    addButton->setIconSize(QSize(50,50));
    addButton->setMinimumSize(50,50);
    addButton->setMaximumSize(50,50);
    layer1->addWidget(addButton);// The horizontal layout
```

3. You can refer to stylesheet examples from Qt [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: This is precisely what I was requesting, thanks a lot! I'll be sure to use the resource you have provided from now on!